# Override list selection in Swing

Tags: java, swing, selection, jlist

I want to make list selection such that when I first select an item it get selected after that when I select second item then both should get selected that is first selection should remain as it is. I have set list selection mode to multiple selection. But still has to press `ctrl` key to do the thing. *I want to do it without pressing `ctrl` key.*

***How to remain list item selected?***

Here is the line where I set the selection mode:

```
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
```

***Edit:***
AS suggested by ***StanislavL*** I tried following but it did not worked for me.

```
            DefaultListSelectionModel model = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
            model.removeSelectionInterval(0, 2);
            user_list.setSelectionModel(model);
```

Answer (score 4):

It is a real well known convention that multi select **requires** pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Same with using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to select a range of values.

Personally I would never spend effort on changing this behaviour, because it would confuse users that are already familiar with other applications.

Comment: +1 I run into this in my company all the time. They want well established conventions to change because "it's what they want"... Is it really what they want? Probably not... not in the long run!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace ListSelectionModel in the list. Use

```
public void setSelectionModel(ListSelectionModel selectionModel)
```

You can use the DefaultListSelectionModel and override

```
public void removeSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)
```

call super.remove() if the items are already selected.

Comment: I tried it but nothing changes. I have added my code in my question

Comment: I don't see where you override the removeSelectionInterval in your code.

Comment: I read its doc about `removeSelectionInterval(nt index0, int index1)` but not able to completely override it. Don't know what to do actually in it. Will you help me a little bit more.